# How do I use multiple iFrames in my html page?

Tags: html, iframe

I just have them in the body of the page one after the other. If I do this with `<object>`, I see them all. With iFrames, I only see the first one.

```
<iframe id="AlertMaintenance" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="AlertMaintenance.html"/>

<iframe id="DelayReason" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="DelayReason.html"/>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to specify a `</iframe>` closing tag. Self-closing tags ( `/>`)  don't work.

Working code:

```
<iframe id="AlertMaintenance" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="AlertMaintenance.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="DelayReason" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="DelayReason.html"></iframe>
```

End tags are required. See also: [MDN: iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: Slightly surprised to find that this remains true in 2023!

Answer (score 4):

Iframe has a closing tag:

```
<iframe ...></iframe>
```

Add em' in.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use selfclosing tags.

Change this to:

```
<iframe id="AlertMaintenance" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="AlertMaintenance.html"></iframe>

<iframe id="DelayReason" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; height:1222px; width:100%;" src="DelayReason.html"></iframe>
```