# MVC Several iFrames on a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view where i'm rendering several iframes (Youtube videos embed with iframe) and only renders the first one. Anyone knows how to fix it? Below I put my view code. Thanks in advance!

```
@model List<DBB.PMI.Cross.Domain.UserMedia>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="form-group">
    <table>
        @foreach (DBB.PMI.Cross.Domain.UserMedia item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe id="ytplayer" width="125" height="100" 
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/@item.IdVideo" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label(item.Comment)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here: 
[How do I use multiple iFrames in my html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068578/how-do-i-use-multiple-iframes-in-my-html-page).

I had to close the iframe tag with

```
</iframe>
```

instead close it self with

```
<iframe src.... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the issue but noticed that you are running a for loop while giving each iframe the same id attribute = "ytplayer" which may be causing the issue.

I would recommend making the id of each iframe unique through each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it, but the error is still there. Thanks